# Local Notification have 2 options 1.oK and second one local notification Action view or anything else

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sdk

Local Notification have 2 options 1.oK and second one local notification Action view or anything else...can we change "OK" button text and do some action on it?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW2) says that,

> The message consists of the application name, a short message, and (in this case) two buttons: Close and View. The button on the right is called the action button and its default title is “View”. An application can customize the title of the action button and can internationalize the button title and the message so that they are in the user’s preferred language.

You cant change the "close" button's text. If you want to change the right button's text, use the following,

```
localNotif.alertAction = @"Show Me"; // Or something else
```

Comment: I want to change text of close button....and want to assign some action...is it possible?

Comment: @user804817, No. Its not possible. That button is used only to close the alert without doing any action.

Comment: even you cant change "close" text?

Comment: @user804817, Yes. You can't change it. Even for the "View" button, you can only change the button text. Nothing else you can change.

Comment: I want to crop recorded video.Record and crop video in an iphone app

Comment: is this possible to crop video?

Comment: also i want to assign different vibrations to contacts...how can i do this any example of accessing contacts and assign ringtone and vibration?

Comment: @user804817, I dont have any idea about video cropping and assigning vibrations. Ask this as separate question. You will get more answers. :-)